# On scroll navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll

I have searched Stackoverflow lot before posting answer.

So I want an extra navigation which will be displayed only when you scroll down little bit..and till the the end of the page.

As you scroll up it stays there but as you reach exact on top it will be hidden and will show main static navigation.

Here is an example of navigation I am talking about.

http://watracz.com/ scroll down little bit.

Regards

Comment: `scrollTop()` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function () {

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollPos >= 100 && !$('#hidden-menu').hasClass('vis')) {
        $('#hidden-menu').addClass('vis');
    }

    if(scrollPos <= 100 && $('#hidden-menu').hasClass('vis')){
        $('#hidden-menu').removeClass('vis');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
    alert("Do stuff");
  }
});
```